# Characterization of $\tau \in S_n$ such that $\sigma:=(1 \space 2)\tau$ commutes with two distinct transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Possibly ancillary to another problem, I want to characterize the permutations $\tau \in S_n$ such that $\sigma:=(1 \space 2)\tau$ commutes with two distinct transpositions. If relevant, we can use the constraint that $\tau$ mustn't be an $n$-cycle.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $\tau=(12)$ then $\sigma$ is the identity so commutes with everything

Comment: Yes, right. I have wrongly posed the question: I'm rather looking for a *characterization* of the set of such $\tau$'s. Shall I edit the question?

Comment: Yes, then you should edit the question body and title